# pdf rendering using pyqt webview

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a template file created in MS Excel which is exported as html. The template file contains multiple field that needs to be filled with parameter using an interactive PyQt4 form application. The problem is that PyQt4 webview correctly renders the file and can be directly printed only when there is single html file but for multiple file (i.e css and xml document generated) it doesn't return the correct output. Without the css and xml file the layout and styles doesn't match and gibberish print is produced. 
the code is as

```
dpi = 50
printer = QtGui.QPrinter()
printer.setResolution(dpi)
printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
printer.setPageMargins(12, 20, 10, 5, QPrinter.Millimeter)

document = QtWebKit.QWebView(self)
document.setHtml(self.template_html
                 ,QUrl("./misc/")) // here "misc" folder contains another   
                                   // folder "template_html_files" containing
                                   // the css and xml file

printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
printer.setOutputFileName("added.pdf")
```

self.template_html contains the html tags of the main generated pages (loaded manually using using `open`) and the following files is generated by MS excel which is to be included

```
filelist.xml
sheet001.htm
stylesheet.css
tabstrip.htm
```

The directory structure is

```
./
|
|-----MainApplication.py
|-----misc
       |
       |-----template_html.html
       |-----template_html_files
                |
                |-------filelist.xml
                |-------sheet001.htm
                |-------stylesheet.css
                |-------tabstrip.htm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the second argument of `QWebView,setHtml()` has to be a `QUrl`.I think, `QUrl` can't be a path-string, it has to be an url, see
[Qt Documentation QUrl](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#details).

the simplest way would be, to use the html-file directly:

```
self.load(QtCore.QUrl('file://path to file')
```

links in head of html like the following are found

```
<LINK type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./misc/Formatierung.CSS">
```

i only got it working with the absolute path to the html-file